# How to properly copy SKTileMapNode in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

When I run `loop` on node everything works fine, node moving correct. But when i run loop on `next` action interrupts when `next` reaches left border of the screen (halfway). I assume something wrong with copy. Thanks!

```
func moveBackground (name: String, speed: CGFloat = 0.01) {


    guard let node = childNode(withName: name) as? SKTileMapNode else {
        fatalError("\(name) node not loaded")
    }


    let width = node.frame.size.width
    let startPositionX = width


    node.position = CGPoint(x: startPositionX , y: 0)


    let next = node.copy() as! SKTileMapNode
    next.tileSet = node.tileSet
    next.position = CGPoint(x: startPositionX , y: 0)
    self.addChild(next)


    let distance = width * 2
    let duration = TimeInterval(speed * distance)


    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -distance, y: 0, duration: duration)
    let resetAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: startPositionX, duration: 0)


    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, resetAction])
    let loop = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)


    //node.run(loop)
    next.run(loop)

}
```

Comment: why are you replacing the next tileSet with the original tileSet? Also what happens to the original node, that is still on screen so you may see some graphic distortion happening

Comment: I copy tileSet from node to next because otherwise next is empty with size 0px and even didn't see it on the screen

Comment: ok there must be a bug with copying tile nodes, you may want to assign a copy of the tileset to next, not the original.  Is your goal to just create an infinite scrolling background?  I would not even take this approach,  I would just extend the end of your map the number of tiles from the beginning that it takes to fill the screen, a "margin" of tiles if you would, and just shift the position when my margin fills up the entire screen.  So my tile map is ABCDEFAB,  I can see 2 letters at any time,  when the latter AB is fully on the screen, I shift it to where the former AB are on screen

Comment: Yes, the goal is infinite background scrolling. ABCDEFAB is very interesting approach to this problem. My be i try it, thank you!

Comment: I can't tell you if this is a proper way to do it but this seems to copy the tile map node properly (and as you noticed copy() does not seem to work properly here):
let map = self.childNode(withName: "tileMap") as! SKTileMapNode
let mapData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: map)
let mapCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: mapData) as! SKTileMapNode